# DOM Node count increase when loading Highcharts documents (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, highcharts

I've got a webpage that loads Highcharts graphs at regular intervals - like a slideshow in a loop.  My problem is that after a few hours of running the web crashes in Chrome (other browsers not an option at the moment) with a "Aw, Snap !  Something went wrong while displaying this webpage. "

Using "Chrome development tools->Timeline" I can see that the "DOM Node Count" increases constantly.(also the document count).

This is a part of a larger web so I can not post the code.  I've however created a page that does things in a similar way.  I load the graph with JQuery.load().

When rotating plain HTML pages the DOM count does not increase (gets garbage collected).

Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Can I do this a different way?  Is this a Highcharts bug?  Any suggestions on how to solve this welcome.

Here is some code that can produce this behavior. (sorry I couldn't get it to work in jsfiddle)
(comment and uncomment in "$(document).ready" function to change between load methods)

I've put this page up here : http://memoryleak.ivarragnarsson.com where you can chose to view a leaky Highcharts version or a standard HTML loading non-leaking version.

"memoryleak.html"

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function UpdateGraphsDiv()
        {
        if (typeof window.chart != 'undefined')
        {
            window.chart.destroy();
        }

            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false, async: false });
            $("#chartcontainer").load("graph.html");
        }

        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            UpdateGraphsDiv(); setInterval(UpdateGraphsDiv, 5000);  //Updates graph in div using JQuery Load
        });


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartcontainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

"graph.html"

```
<div id='container1' style='min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function ()
    {
        $('#container1').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style=""font-size:10px"">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style=""color:{series.color};padding:0"">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style=""padding:0""><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

            }]
        });
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

Please tell me how to stop this accumulation of DOM Nodes.

Comment: Does using `$("#divpagediv").html('');` instead of `.empty();` help?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change anything.  Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: I'm almost positive it's not your code then, sounds more like highcharts keeps references to dead nodes and it's leaking

Comment: Before recreating chart in the same div, make sure you have called `chart.destroy()` before.

Comment: Thank you Pawel.  I changed the code slightly as you suggested. DOM count is still increasing with every new load (JQuery) but at a much slower rate. (2-4 DOM objects pr. new load).  I've not determined where the leak is coming from ( ie. Highcharts of perhaps JQuery?)

Comment: Could you tell which objects remains?

Comment: I'm not proficient with the Chrome tool but it looks to me that there is one Div with class "highcharts-container"  and id="highcharts-0".
The Context points to line 9792 in highcharts.src.js. 
   `pointer['_' + eventConfig[2]] = function (e) {`
(Also looks like another empty div is there.)

Comment: I've put a website (http://memoryleak.ivarragnarsson.com) so anyone interested can test in Chrome without having to copy the code into files.  I've also added the "destroy" as Pawel suggested (which helped but did not solve the problem completely.

Comment: It's strange that it leaks less when you run chart.destroy before adding a new chart to the same div - this should happen by default - see http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/R2kgh/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As agreed, calling `chart.destroy()` resolves most part of DOM nodes increasing issue. According to example by Ivar, I can see that it doesn't depend on Highcharts (see attached chart) - looks like `jQuery.load()` doesn't clean properly previous content.

Left: without chart || Right: with chart [image: Left: without chart || Right: with chart]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Pawel. I see that you are not on windows.  When I do these test on Windows, "Chrome Version 29.0.1547.76 m" the DOM Node count on page always goes to 271 when garbage is collected.  Can anyone confirm this?
(It was stabilizing at 293 but I added a $("#chartcontainer").html('') infront of the load() - doing same changes on Highcharts page did not change the constant increase in DOM nodes)

Comment: Tried Ivar's example(http://memoryleak.ivarragnarsson.com/nomemoryleak.html) and after garbage collecting the node count always went down again.  So no memory leak.  (Chrome v29.0.1547.66).  I've also noticed this memory(node) leak with Highcharts.

Comment: Confirmed - just needed to use it for more that 15 minutes to see memory leak.

Comment: Ran test for 1.5 hours.  Node count always goes down like shown [Here](http://memoryleak.ivarragnarsson.com/monitor_Chrome.png)

Comment: I've been testing quite a bit and concluded that the chrome devtool is holding on to the DOM Nodes in the case of Highcharts reload page.  When one stops and starts the timeline recorder the node count drops down.  Thanks Pawel for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the dynamic interaction part of HighCharts. Then I would create images of your charts using PhantomJS Webserver. Then load the chart images into your divs. This way HighCharts lib is not killing the load from client interaction.

Using PhantomJS is very simple to create HighCharts on the fly.

http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs